# Rectangle thumbnail and item-text-wrap with Ionic?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm very new to Ionic and I have a simple question that I couldn't find in the documentation.

Is there any way to use Ionic classes to simply align the content which is now below the image, to the left?

The code I currently have is:

```
   <ion-item class="item-left item-text-wrap">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Poster">
   <h2>Title</h2>
   <h3>Something else</h3>
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/e8f309f71714 
You dont need to do any styling for this, ionic thumbnails will be of best use to you, see here [Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-thumbnails).
This is how you will do

```
<ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" alt="Poster" class="customized-image">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <h2>Something else</h2>
  <p>your large content goes here</p>
</ion-item>
```

`item-thumbnail-left` class is provided by ionic. You will only have to make some style class to make image rectangle. Because by default image will be square.This is how class can look like

```
.customized-image{
  max-height: 100px !important;
}
```

`customized-image` class should be added to image tag.That is it, no more custom styling.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I thought there was built-in ionic class to avoid custom, styling but works fine.

Comment: you just need styling for image height, everything else is built in :)

Answer (score 1):

You Can acomplish it using inline-block

```
.item-left img {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 33%; /* or waterver you need = w1 */
   vertical-align: top;
}
.item-left h2,.item-left h3 {
   display:inline-block;
   width: 66%; /* (100-w1)% */
   vertical-align: top;
}
```